# How to set pixels to "Console Windows" by passing "String Pointer" in C?

Tags: c, winapi, graph, pixel, mingw32

I know how to set pixels to "Console Windows" by using "SetPixel()"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145078(v=vs.85).aspx

But it wastes **a lot of time** to call this function and draw every pixels to it.

Is there any feasible way to set every pixels by passing string (pointer), and call function one time, but set every pixels?

Comment: Um, console windows are character-based, not pixel-based.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Yep, I know. But still, we can draw in Console Windows. Cool? Maybe you can view [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073077/why-the-black-area-doesnt-show-properly-in-console-windows) I posted before :-)

Comment: What you are doing is not supported and may stop working at any time. (Indeed there are many popular versions of Windows where it does not work already.) Make sure your customers understand this.

Comment: @Raymond Chen But MSDN says: [SetPixel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145078(v=vs.85).aspx) can run in all the version after Windows 2000 Pro. Doesn't it?

Comment: `SetPixel` is not the issue. Partying on a window you do not own is the issue. It's like saying "I'm using a telescoping arm to get the books from my neighbor's bookshelf. The manual for the telescoping arm says that it works for retrieving books from high bookshelves." The telescoping arm is fine. But you shouldn't be breaking into your neighbor's house and taking his books without permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "Console Windows" or "String", and what they have to do with SetPixel().

However it is true that modifying bitmaps using repeated calls to SetPixel() is very inefficient because it has high overhead. Instead, copy out the bitmap data to a buffer using [GetDIBits()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), modify the buffer, and once you're done copy them back into the bitmap using SetDIBits().

Comment: Note also that `SetDIBits` needs a buffer device context, and writing to the primary device context directly with `StretchDIBits` might be easier than that, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56692411/257568