# C - faster SetPixels in Console Windows

Tags: c, bitmap, console, window

I am searching for a method to draw pixels in a console window (application). The generic methods SetPixel / SetPixelV are very slow.

I want to do a minimal and static snake game. (The snake will just move if you press a key). My map size is 200x200.

I do operations on an array of a point structure. My point structure holds just the RGB values casted as unsigned chars.(3 bytes, point.r point.g, e.g. Point map[width*height]) the operations are optimized with open mp.

I am done with filling it white and put a 20px border for the playground. The rest is not a problem.

But a call to SetPixel 40000 times is very slow on my machine.

Is there any possibility of speeding it up? I found something like bitblt but I don't have any idea how to transform my array to bitblt and put it on a console window.

There some simple frameworks like SDL or direct2d etc.. But that creates a new window. I want it on the console window.

@Edit
I don't have a string pointer and I don't have a bitmap. I just have a raw data array that contains the RGB values as unsigned chars in a structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set pixels to "Console Windows" by passing "String Pointer" in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087493/how-to-set-pixels-to-console-windows-by-passing-string-pointer-in-c)

Comment: Please read the last paragraph of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20087631/11683) in the linked question.